# check if the text is not questio type and also contains some specific words

Tags: java, regex

I want to make sure that the text is not a question type and also contains at least one of these:watch live  watch speech live  #breaking  #breaking news

so I wrote the code as follow:

```
private static void containsQuestion(String commentstr){
     String urlPattern = "^(?!.*?\\?)(watch live|watch speech live|#breaking|#breaking news)";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
}
```

but when I try it with for example:

```
They say 2's company; is 3 a crowd watch live on...
```

I expect to see yes in the console since it is matched but nothing happens
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your use of start anchor `^`,

Either remove it:

```
String urlPattern = 
        "(?!.*?\\?)(watch live|watch speech live|#breaking|#breaking news)";
```

Or place `.*?` before your keywords to match any # of chars before your phrases:

```
String urlPattern =
       "^(?!.*?\\?).*?(watch live|watch speech live|#breaking|#breaking news)";
```

**Due to use of `^` your regex is trying to match all those phrases only at start.**

Comment: Thank you now the problem is when I try it with a sentence of question type it matches which should not for example this sentence should not match: They say 2's company? watch live on...

Comment: ok check my updated code. You can use `"^(?!.*?\\?).*?(watch live|watch speech live|#breaking|#breaking news)"`

Comment: perfect I am a little bit confused can u explain the role of ? after .*

Comment: That is for non-greedy match. In this case you can use `.*` as well as your regex only wants to match those phrases anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow more characters before/after you key words:
Try this:

```
/^(?!.*?\?).*(watch live|watch speech live|\#breaking|\#breaking news).*/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/uS1xQ4/2